# finish activity from an other one

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity for my menu events:

```
public class GlobalMenu extends Activity{

    private MenuItem item;

    public boolean event(MenuItem item){
        this.item = item;
        // Handle item selection
        switch (this.item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_stop:
                finish();
                return true;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And I use it like this

```
GlobalMenu gm = new GlobalMenu();

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return gm.event(item);
}
```

But the finish didn't work, I think I need to link it with an application but I don't know how to do

Thanks

Comment: *What* are you trying to do?  You should never create an instance of an Activity like this `GlobalMenu gm = new GlobalMenu();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of All, You can't make a Object or Instance of Android Activity.
like this

```
GlobalMenu gm = new GlobalMenu();
```

You have to pass a Context of GlobalMenu Activity to other Activity or Class and then call finish on this.

Like,

```
((GlobalMenu)mContext).finish();
```

Here **mContext** is a reference of `GlobalMenu Activity`.